# Can't unit testing a method that gets values app.config

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

In a .NET Core 3.1 console application I have some methods that use app.config to get some values (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["my-key"]). It gets the values correctly when running the application.

However when I try to unitTest (with Visual Studio TestTools) these methods the values I get are null. I tried creating an app.config file inside the unitTest project and using ConfigurationManager directly in the unitTest method, still null values.

I read there are some workarounds like mocking the configuration or passing these values as parameters to these methods, however I don't think these workarounds are the cleanest thing, also then my unitTests couldn't really check if my configuration file is alright.

So, does anyone know why the ConfigurationManager get null values while unit testing? Is it because its a static class by chance? Also is there a way to use it somehow?

Comment: *Don't* use `app.config` and `ConfigurationManager`. Those are only used to ease the migration of .NET Framework applications. Use .NET Core's Configuration middleware instead (IConfiguration etc). This will allow you to create a new Configuration object in unit tests from eg an in-memory Dictionary without the application noticing the change

Comment: The reason for the `null`s is that only executable applications read settings from `app.config`. A test project is a library, not an executable. The executable is the NUnit or XUnit test runner

Comment: Oh... So ether solution (using IConfiguration or NUnit/XUnit) should work if i understand well ?

Comment: Oh using IConfiguration worked well, thanks!